# Loop para soma de campos MySql

Tags: mysql

Caros, possuo duas tabelas, onde a tabela1 possui colunas de A1 até A4, B1 até B4, C1 até C4 e D1 até D4, todas do tipo decimal (4,2) e com n linhas; e a tabela2 possui 3 colunas sendo Total1, Total2 e Total3, onde deve ser apresentado a soma dos campos da tabela1.
De forma grosseira criei a seguinte procedure para atualizar a tabela2:

```
    DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS teste$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE teste()
       BEGIN
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(A1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(B1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(C1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(A2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(B2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(C2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(A3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(B3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(C3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(A4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(B4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL1 = (select sum(C4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(A1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(B1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(C1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(A2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(B2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(C2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(A3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(B3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(C3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(A4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(B4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL2 =  (select sum(C4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =  (select sum(A1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(B1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(C1) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C1';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(A2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(B2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(C2) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C2';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(A3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(B3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(C3) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C3';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(A4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'A4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(B4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'B4';
update tabela2 set TOTAL3 =   (select sum(C4) from tabela1) where coluna = 'C4';
END$$
DELIMITER ;
all teste();
```

Porém este tipo de código repetitivo não é legal, estou tentando usar a procedure abaixo, porém o sum não funciona para a variavel str, segue codigo:

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS teste$$
CREATE PROCEDURE teste()
BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;
 DECLARE str1 varchar(2);
 DECLARE str2 varchar(2);
 DECLARE str3 varchar(2);
  SET x = 1;
    WHILE x  <= 4 DO
        SET str1 =  concat('A',x);
        SET str2 =  concat('B',x);
        SET str3 =  concat('C',x);
        update tabela set TOTAL = (select sum(str1) from tabela2) where coluna = str1;
        update tabela set TOTAL = (select sum(str2) from tabela2) where coluna = str2;
        update tabela set TOTAL = (select sum(str3) from tabela2) where coluna = str3;
        SET  x = x + 1; 
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

call teste();
```

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de criar este looping.

Obrigado.

Comment: O problema parece-me que está no `concat('A',x)` cujo mesmo não te devolve a referência a uma coluna mas sim a string `A1` por exemplo.

Comment: E a coluna "coluna"?

Comment: coluna é o nome da coluna mesmo, nesta coluna eu vou ter os valores A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2...até C4, fora esta coluna eu a coluna TOTAL, onde deverá ser armazenado o resultado da soma dos campos.

Comment: Realmente, acredito que o problema esteja no concat, porem nao encontrei um modo de usar o loop para as 4 variações de A,B,C. Não encontrei um meio de unir as strings A,B,C com a variavel x, de modo que o sum reconheça como o nome de uma coluna.

Comment: @Thiago Precisas fazer um `SELECT` dentro do `concat()` para apanhares o valor... Eu estou sem tempo agora, mas podes ir olhando para este [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b7f/2/0), faz o que precisas.

Comment: Só pra continuar entendendo. No primeiro código você tem `total1`, `total2` e `total3`. No segundo apenas `total`. Entendi que na verdade você também tem um campo `coluna` onde fica tipo **coluna** A1 - **total** - sum(A1), **coluna** A2 - **total** - sum(A2), e por ai vai. É isso?

Comment: Ja havia tentado usar o select(concat()), porem o sum nao reconhece ainda.

Answer (score 1):

`TB_DADOS` (seria a sua tabela1)

```
| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|  5 |  1 |  8 |  2 |  9 |  2 | 16 |  1 |  1 | 11 |  3 | 21 |
|  6 |  4 |  4 |  5 |  1 |  7 |  1 |  4 | 17 | 12 |  6 |  9 |
|  7 |  2 |  3 |  4 | 10 |  2 |  5 | 11 |  8 |  2 |  9 | 10 |
```

`TB_TOTAL` (seria a sua tabela2)

```
| coluna | total  |
|--------|--------|
|   A1   |  18    |
|   A2   |   7    |
|   A3   |  15    |
|   A4   |  11    |
|   B1   |  20    |
|   B2   |  11    |
|   B3   |  22    |
|   B4   |  16    |
|   C1   |  26    |
|   C2   |  25    |
|   C3   |  18    |
|   C4   |  40    |
```

Ao meu ver, com essa estrutura, você nem precisa usar essa segunda tabela, para o total.

Pode criar uma `view` que retorne o total

```
CREATE VIEW `vw_total` AS
  SELECT 
    SUM(A1) as A1, 
    SUM(A2) as A2,
    SUM(A3) as A3, 
    SUM(A4) as A4, 
    SUM(B1) as B1, 
    SUM(B2) as B2,
    SUM(B3) as B3, 
    SUM(B4) as B4, 
    SUM(C1) as C1, 
    SUM(C2) as C2,
    SUM(C3) as C3, 
    SUM(C4) as C4
  FROM tb_dados;
```

O retorno dessa `view` seria:

```
select * from vw_total;

| A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
| 18 |  7 | 15 | 11 | 20 | 11 | 22 | 16 | 26 | 25 | 18 | 40 |
```

Para capturar o total de um único campo:

```
select A1 from vw_total;

| A1 | 
|----|
| 18 |
```

Porém, se essa tabela de total é usado constantemente e a tabela de dados tem volume, não é o ideal usar essa view já que ela aplicaria em todas suas chamadas funções em todas as colunas precisando de todas suas linhas, o que poderia ser exaustivo.

Pra isso pode ser usado a procedure e a tabela para armazenamento do total. A procedure corrigida para executar, deve usar `prepare` e `execute`, executando querys definidas em string.

```
delimiter $$

create procedure `atualiza_total`()
begin
 declare x     int;
 declare str   varchar(2);
 set x = 1;
    while x <= 12 do
        case
          when x <= 4 then 
            set str =  concat('A',x);
          when x <= 8 then 
            set str =  concat('B',x-4);
          else
            set str =  concat('C',x-8);
        end case;

        set @query = concat("update tb_total set total = (select sum(",str,") ","from tb_dados) where coluna = '",str,"'; ");

        prepare stmt1 from @query;
        execute stmt1;

        set  x = x + 1; 
    end while;
end
```

Funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7ecc/8).